# Clashing UITableView Editing functions

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, edit

I've previously implemented deletion for cells in my `UITableView` by using the following code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        feedTable.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

However, now I want to add a custom action for the cells so I've added this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit", handler: { (action, indexPath) in
    })
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
    }
    edit.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    return [delete, edit]
}
```

Now I'm confused whether I even need the original `commit editingStyle` function. Should I just move all my editing handling code (`feedTable.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)`) to the new function?

It seems to me like there are many different functions that have to do with `UITableViewCell` editing and I'm confused about which ones to use when.

Answer (score 0):

*Should I just move all my editing handling code (feedTable.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)) to the new function?*

**The answer to your question : Yes**

When you implement the tableView( _: editActionsForRowAtIndexPath: ) method, the table view will no longer generate the Delete button for you. This is why you need to create your own Delete button.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

   let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit", handler: { (action, indexPath) in
         // your handling code
   })

   let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
         // your handling code
   }

   // buttons colors
   edit.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
   delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

   return [delete, edit]
}
```